# How do I extend my Ubuntu partition?

Tags: partitioning

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 in a 90GB partition of when I "shrinked" from the C drive of which has Windows 7.

I have a 500GB HDD. I want to give Ubuntu an extra 100GB.

How do I do this please?

Answer (score 0):

boot from the live cd or usb drive you used to install ubuntu. Run gparted and resize at your leisure. Have a look at the "Using GParted" section of [this page.](http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/#Using%20GParted)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is GParted through live USB/CD.

But note that if you don’t have free space after the Ubuntu prtition, while expanding GParted will move data which takes long time and is riskful for data loss. So the best way is:

1. to make a new partition after the Ubuntu partition;
2. make this new partition empty by moving files through Nautilus;
3. then go back to GParted again, delete the new partition (which makes it unallocated) and expand the Ubuntu partition over it.